# Double slashes return infinitely results, when string "find" function is used

Tags: c++

Here is code of this problem:

```
        while ((found = line.find('\"', found)) != std::string::npos)
        {
            cout << "key found at line:" << found << endl;
            line.replace(found, 1, "\\\"");
        }
```

Output:
key found at line:12
key found at line:12
key found at line:12
key found at line:12
..
..
..
∞

Find function does not return result correctly. Why?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: This won't run infinitely.  Eventually it will run out of memory.

Answer (score 2):

`found` will be the index of `\` in `\"` inserted by the `line.replace`. Therefore, `"` in `\"` will be found in the next iteration and this will be repeated infinitely.

You should add `2` to `found` (`found += 2;`) after the `line.replace` to have it search for next `"` after the replacement.

Comment: You have Right. Thank you for Answer. Now code works correctly.